# Why any expectation value can be computed by this path integral, and not just the time-ordered ones?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, path-integral

This is quite a basic question about the path integral. In Polchinki's String Theory book, Chapter 2, he says:

> Expectation values are defined by the path integral
>
> $$\langle \mathscr{F}[X]\rangle=\int[dX] \exp(-S)\mathscr{F}[X],\tag{2.1.14}$$
>
> where $\mathscr{F}[X]$ is *any functional* of $X$, such as a product of local operators.

Now I believe I have gotten something wrong. My issue is with the *any functional* part. If I recall what the path integral gives are *time-ordered mean values*, so that it would not give the mean of "any functional of $X$".

In fact, in Appendix A, Polchinski reviews the path integral. He derives this result, and in fact in Eq. (A.1.17) we see:

$$\int[dq]_{q_i,0}^{q_f,T}\exp (iS)q(t)q(t')=\langle q_f,T|\mathrm{T}[\hat{q}(t)\hat{q}(t')]|q_i,0\rangle\tag{A.1.17}.$$

So I confess I am a bit lost, but that's probably something *very basic* that I'm missing.

How to reconcille Polchinski's statement, Eq. (2.1.14), that we may get the expectation value of *any functional of $X$* by that path integral, with the fact that the path integral actually computes time-ordered expectation values? Is there some way in which the path integral may, in fact, compute the expectation value of *any* functional?

Comment: I don't understand the question. In the text quoted, Polchinski uses (2.1.14) as the *definition* of the expectation value of any functional, i.e. he is *defining* the expectation value of "any functional" to be the same as the expectation value of its time-ordered version. What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: $\langle F\rangle$ means $\langle 0|T[F]|0\rangle$.

Comment: @ACuriousMind if that is the case, then I fail to grasp the motivation for said definition. Is it because in the end we only need the time-ordered ones (e.g., in computing the $S$-matrix), so we simply don't care with the non-time-ordered ones? I mean, in the operator formalism we have a distinction between the expectation value of $\mathscr{F}[X]$ and $\mathrm{T} \mathscr{F}[X]$. Why would it be reasonable to define the expectation value of a functional to be the same as the expectation value of its time-ordered version? Wouldn't this even clash with the operator formalism?

Comment: Frankly, I've never seen anyone keep writing the $T$ for time-ordered expectation values beyond elementary intro texts. There is so little use for "non-time-ordered expectation values" that you'll see n-point functions in many places simply written as $\langle \phi(x_1)\dots\phi(x_n)\rangle$, and the time-order is implicit. I don't know what sources you're reading that always carefully keep mentioning the time order, but they are not representative of the majority of theoretical QFT.

Comment: Ok, I see that it is then a matter of conventions and wording. The whole point in the end seems to be that since the correlation functions that are useful are the time-ordered ones, we focus on these and assume time-ordering by default. Anyway, thanks for pointing this out @ACuriousMind.

Comment: @user1620696 It is not true that only time-ordered correlators are useful. You study out-of-time-ordered-correlators (OTOCs) in non-equilibrium QFT. See Schwinger-Keldysh theory and refs in this paper, for instance - https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.08335

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, eq. (2.1.14) is in the Euclidean formulation, while eq. (A.1.17) is in the Minkowskian formulation. The operators inside the expectation value on the LHS of eq. (2.1.14) are implicitly assumed to be radially ordered.